# Swift - template parameter

Tags: swift, templates

I'm wondering if there is a way to do the equivalent of `C++`'s templating, to define a generic type base on some integer. I know of Swift's Generic Type, but I don't want to provide a Type but an Int.

In C++, it would look like :

```cpp
template <int N>
class Vector {
  int values[N];
}
```

And in `Swift`, I'd like to use it like

```swift
let vector = Vector<3>(1, 2, 4)
print(vector.sum())
```

It seems weird that Swift provides a way to template based on Type but not on int. I could almost achieve it using generics and `sizeof(T)`, passing `Int`, `Float` or `Double`, but that'd be aweful.

Comment: Swift does not have such a feature. How many dimensions of vectors do you need anyway? Most likely just 2D, 3D, 4D, right? Is it really that much trouble to create 3 structs? I wouldn't imagine there to be a lot of code in these structs anyway, so it is not much duplication.

Comment: Well I'll need up to 6D, and I'd rather not duplicate anything. I need to implement all common vector operation : norm, add, multiply etc...

Comment: Well, look at what the swift standard library did with the `SIMD` vectors. They have 2, 3, 4, 8, 16, 32, and 64 dimensions. Actually the operations don't need to be duplicated if you are fine with implementing them with arrays. Have common methods and initialisers that convert them to and from arrays, then just implement the operations once by operating on arrays. Alternatively, consider source code generation, which I think is how they did the `SIMD` vectors.

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunate that Swift doesn't support this, so I ended up using some protocol to define an integer value.

```swift
protocol SizeableClass {
    static func size() -> Int
}

struct One : SizeableClass {
    static func size() -> Int { 1 }
}
struct Two : SizeableClass {
    static func size() -> Int { 2 }
}
struct Three : SizeableClass {
    static func size() -> Int { 3 }
}


class Vector<S: SizeableClass, T: SignedNumeric> {
    let size = S.size()
    var values: Array<T>
    
    init(_ values: [T]) {
        self.values = values
    }
    
    static func +(_ first: Vector<S, T>, _ second: Vector<S, T>) -> Vector<S, T> {
        return Vector(
            zip(first.values, second.values).map {
                $0 + $1
            }
        )
    }
    
    static prefix func -(_ vector: Vector<S, T>) -> Vector<S, T> {
        return Vector(vector.values.map { -$0 })
    }
    
    static func -(_ first: Vector<S, T>, _ second: Vector<S, T>) -> Vector<S, T> {
        return first + -second
    }
    
    static func *(_ lambda: T, _ vector: Vector<S, T>) -> Vector<S, T> {
        return Vector(vector.values.map {
            $0 * lambda
        })
    }
}
```

Type checking works great (can't add `Vector<Three, Int>` with `Vector<Two, Int>` for example), though it's a bit heavy to write.
I'm open to suggestions!